# How to push a widget with Navigator into only a portion of the screen?

Tags: flutter, routes, widget, push, navigator

I have the device screen divided in two, a top view and a bottom view. I would like to push a new view with a Navigator from the BottomView by doing: `Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/nameHere')`. However, I need the new view to be pushed in place of only the bottom view, not the entire screen, as it happens instead.

Here's my main.dart:

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      darkTheme: ThemeData(),
      initialRoute: homeRoute,
      routes: {
        homeRoute: (context) => const HomeView(),
        newViewRoute: (context) => const NewView(),
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

my HomeView:

```
class HomeView extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeView({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        bottom: false,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const Expanded(
              child TopView(),
            ),
            const Expanded(
              child: BottomView(),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and my BottomView, where I push the new view, which I'd like to appear only in the bottom part of the screen:

```
class BottomView extends StatelessWidget {
  const BottomView({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context)
          .pushNamed(newViewRoute);
        }
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks to everybody for helping!

Comment: You can't do that with a single navigator. You may try to add a specific navigator for each parts but it's uncommon. You'll need to declare them with 2 GlobalKey<NavigatorState> and use those to make your push

Comment: Thanks! Is there maybe a more polished way to do that? I don't necessarily need to go for a Navigator. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome ! You can still try to show/hide your widgets placed in a `Stack` and play with the `Visibility` widget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

*This solution Does not require any external library*

If you need the top widget to be fixed and the navigation to replace only the bottom screen, you can create a base widget that would wrap the whole widget, and this base widget would not be affected by the flutter navigator.

**Example**

Create a baseview like this

```dart
class BaseView extends StatelessWidget {
  const BaseView({super.key, required this.child});
  final Widget child;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        TopView(), // the top view that does not change
        child, // child widget that changes
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Your `main.dart` should include the `BaseView` in the builder as shown below

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      darkTheme: ThemeData(),
      initialRoute: homeRoute,
      builder: (context, child) => BaseView(child: child!),
      routes: {
        homeRoute: (context) => const BottomRoute1(),
        newViewRoute: (context) => const BottomRoute2(),
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

with this solution, all the routes you create would be rendered on the bottom of the screen and using the default flutter navigation changes the bottom widgets. This can be used to create fixed top or bottom navigations for mobile applications or flutter websites.

I hope this solves your problem.

#### Exceptions

if you get an error like this while navigating using named routes
[image: error while navigating]

add a navigator key in the `main.dart`

```dart
GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      darkTheme: ThemeData(),
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey, // add navigator key to material app
      initialRoute: homeRoute,
      builder: (context, child) => BaseView(child: child!),
      routes: {
        homeRoute: (context) => const BottomRoute1(),
        newViewRoute: (context) => const BottomRoute2(),
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

You can now use this navigator in your app to navigate as follows

```dart
navigatorKey.currentState!.pushNamed(routeName);
```

This should solve any problem you have.
You can checkout my project built using this method [here](https://github.com/AnthonyAniobi/Portfolio)

Happy coding